# Realtek Ethernet unclaimed network

Tags: ethernet, connection, wired

recently installed ubuntu 20.04 and tried connecting through ethernet but not working. Ran lshw -C network and found this out:
[image]

Comment: Any workarounds

Comment: Search for rtl8125 here on AU.